# How to apply multiple validations to an argument in bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that `reads` input from the user and validates if the inputted value exists (non-blank) and is an **even integer**. I'm using the terse `test "$1"` to test if input exists but combining it with other validation methods does not seem to work. My validation methods are like so:

```
readValidBookLength() {
  BOOKLENGTH=$1

  while ! [ isValidBookLength $BOOKLENGTH ] && ! [ isBookLengthNumeric $BOOKLENGTH ] && [isBookLengthEvenNumber $BOOKLENGTH]; do
    echo -e 'Book length? (HINT: An even number!): \c'
    read -r BOOKLENGTH
  done    
}

isValidBookLength() {
  test "$1" 
}

isBookLengthNumeric() {
  echo "I GOT HERE!"
  BOOKLENGTH=$1

  echo "${BOOKLENGTH}"
  reg='^[0-9]+$'
  if ! [[ $BOOKLENGTH =~ $reg ]] ; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

isBookLengthEvenNumber() {
  echo "I GOT HERE 2!"
  BOOKLENGTH=$1
  echo "${BOOKLENGTH}"
  if [ $((BOOKLENGTH%2)) -eq 0 ] ; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi  
}
```

Is this pattern of seeking a valid input after multiple validations correct. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put `[` before the calls to your validation functions. `[` is a short name for the `test` command. You also need to group all the tests together and negate the whole group:

```
while ! { isValidBookLength "$BOOKLENGTH" && isBookLengthNumeric $BOOKLENGTH && isBookLengthEvenNumber $BOOKLENGTH; }; do
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the loop to continue to execute if any of the tests fail. That means you should use `||`, not `&&`, to combine the tests.